# Move user in Active Directory with server

Tags: c#, active-directory

The problem:

I get a "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." error when moving a user in Active Directory with C# when including the server as part of the LDAP path.

```
user.MoveTo( new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://SERVER_IP/" + newOU));
```

SERVER_IP is the IP address of the server and newOU is the new OU to which to move the user.

Background:

1. I have to specify the server IP, because this runs on a different domain.
2. IMPORTANT: All the other updates I make to the user's attributes work fine...even creating new accounts. I am indeed using the server IP in that other code.
3. If I run the above code on the same domain it works, no error.

The problem seems to be that the MoveTo does not work properly when also specifying a server in the LDAP path.  I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  Programmer error.

That DirectoryEntry call is the only place in my code that I didn't include the AD username and password.  I hate when I do that.